# JRuby Closing an AWT frame

Tags: ruby, jruby, awt, jogl

I decided to check out JRuby and JOGL to see if I could get some graphics sim stuff running. I've got the classpath set up and the OpenGL things included properly. Following some tutorials, they suggest using an AWT frame instead of a Swing one, as Swing won't support graphics acceleration (which is really what I'm looking for).

I can't figure out how to *close* the AWT frame from Ruby, however. I have a WindowAdapter that fires a `Kernel.exit` event when the close button on the frame is clicked. It looks like this:

```
class Controller < WindowAdapter
  def windowClosing(event)
    Kernel.exit
  end
end
```

The Frame adds this with `add_window_listener(Controller.new)`. The event successfully fires when I click the close button, but it spits out the following error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (SystemExit) exit`

Calling Kernel.exit from the Frame's initialize successfully exits the program. So I'm not sure why calling it from the listener fails. I know in java you can define an anonymous WindowAdapter inline, but I have no idea what the syntax for that would be in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some extra searching and experimentation and found an answer. It appears to be a quirk of the Ruby implementation in the JVM. Calling `exit` or `Kernel.exit` from inside the WindowAdapter is useless.

Calling `java.lang.System.exit(0)`, however, *does* work. I'm not sure why the distinction should make a difference. I would expect `exit` to alias to the Java system command, but it apparently doesn't Hope this is helpful to anyone else who might run into the same problem.